# Click with CasperJS doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using casperjs for scraping content. First I want to click some datepicker `input#ControlGroupCompactView_AvailabilitySearchInputCompactViewdate_picker_display_id_1`

So when I clicked that, the datepicker popup should show up, but it doesn't.

My code is this

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    $("#ControlGroupCompactView_AvailabilitySearchInputCompactViewdate_picker_display_id_1").click();
});
```

but failed...
I tried something more like this...

```
var selector = "input#ControlGroupCompactView_AvailabilitySearchInputCompactViewdate_picker_display_id_1";
casper.waitForSelector(selector);
casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    document.querySelector(selector).click();
});
```

but failed too...
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS has a `click` function which works almost always better that `element.click()` or `$element.click()`.

```
var selector = "input#ControlGroupCompactView_AvailabilitySearchInputCompactViewdate_picker_display_id_1";
casper.waitUntilVisible(selector)
    .thenClick(selector)
    .wait(100) // little time for the picker to open: adjust to your needs
    .then(function(){
        this.capture("screenshot.png"); // make sure the picker is there
    });
```

You can also use `casper.waitUntilVisible` to wait for the date picker to open instead of `casper.wait(100)`.

In case this doesn't solve your problem, you will have to investigate further by registering to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

---

By the way, your second snippet cannot work, because `selector` is undefined inside `casper.evaluate`. `casper.evaluate` is the sandboxed page context. You have to explicitly pass variables in and out and they can't be complex.